# How can I provide a "live updated" count/list of records in my Android app?

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite, ormlite

I'm creating an app (using SQLite) where the user selects ingredients they have in their house.  As they select ingredients, I want to update an ActionTab to show the correct # of recipes the user can make based upon the ingredients they own.  The ActionTab itself contains a fragment that is a list (CursorAdapter) of the matching recipes.

From everything I've come across, it seems like I may need to create a ContentProvider to do this.  However, reading the "decide if you need a content provider" section of the [Android ContentProvider docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#BeforeYouStart), I see the following:

> You don't need a provider to use an SQLite database if the use is entirely within your own application.

This seems to contradict what I thought based upon other articles available in the wild.  So my question is, do I really need to create a ContentProvider to live update this data?  Or is there a better way?  (In case it matters, I'm working with OrmLite.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across this issue, you do NOT need to create a ContentProvider.  Simple specify a custom notification URI on your cursor that needs to be live updated:

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContentResolver(), uri)
```

Then, whenever a relevant change occurs in your app that should trigger a live update, call the following using the same URI value:

```
getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null)
```

Hope this helps anyone who has the same question!